# angular ui-router browser compatibility

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Looked all over, but can't find spec on the Angular ui-router browser compatibility.
Does anybody know? Is IE9 supported?

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/390#issuecomment-24058684) I would assume that they still support IE9.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293118/angularui-compatible-browsers

Comment: We use ui-router with IE9 no problems.