# AngularJS Bootstrap Tabset tab navigation between tabs not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angular-ui, angular-ui-tabset

The application is all fine and working in modern browsers. However, I need it to work in Internet Explorer 8, and it seems that **ng-repeat** for my tabs is not working. I can't navigate between tabs, Hover and active tabs is working but the content does not change.

Take a look at my codes.

HTML

```
<ul tabset id="tab-control">
    <ul tab class="dropdown-toggle" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.Name}}"  
        id="{{tab.codeListe}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled" ng-click="tab_click(tab.codeListe, $index)" 
        ng-right-click="rightClick()" ng-mouseover="tab_hover()" ng-mouseleave="tab_leave(tab.codeListe,tab.Name)" icon-pos>
            <!-- ng-repeat should fire here -->

        <section class="accordion">
            <!-- Content Goes here -->
        </section>

    </ul>
</ul>
```

These are the elements when I am using modern browers, and it's working just fine.. 
    (from ChromeDevTools).

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}" ng-transclude="" style="width: 600px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
         <!-- ngRepeat: tab in tabs -->

         <!-- <li> contains my ng-click and my ng-rightclick functions. I need them.-->

    <li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" tab="" class="dropdown-toggle ng-isolate-scope" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="1A Test" id="126279" active="tab.active" disabled="disabled" ng-click="tab_click(tab.codeListe, $index)" ng-right-click="rightClick()" ng-mouseover="tab_hover()" ng-mouseleave="tab_leave(tab.codeListe,tab.Name)" icon-pos="" style="width: 200px;">
        <a ng-click="select()" tab-heading-transclude="" class="ng-binding wrap" style="">1A Test</a>
        <div class="close-tab icon-delete"></div>
    </li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabs -->

    <li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" tab="" class="dropdown-toggle ng-isolate-scope" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="1B Test" id="126290" active="tab.active" disabled="disabled" ng-click="tab_click(tab.codeListe, $index)" ng-right-click="rightClick()" ng-mouseover="tab_hover()" ng-mouseleave="tab_leave(tab.codeListe,tab.Name)" icon-pos="" style="width: 200px;">
        <a ng-click="select()" tab-heading-transclude="" class="ng-binding wrap" style="">1B Test</a>
        <div class="close-tab icon-delete"></div>
    </li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabs -->
</ul>
```

This one is from my IE8 Developer Tools.

```
<div class="tabbable ng-isolate-scope" id="tab-control" tabset="" jQuery17106089792077578351="109">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="width: 968px;" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}" ng-transclude="" jQuery17106089792077578351="110">

         <!-- ngRepeat: tab in tabs -->
         <!-- nothing happens here. <li> from ng-repeat does not append 
             This is my main problem, because this contains the click and
             rightclick function I need to navigate between tabs-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

The tabset view is okay, I followed this one. [AngularUI - Compatible browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293118/angularui-compatible-browsers)

Update.

I have no problem with my functions so I did not include it.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular 1.3 has dropped support for ie8.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)